create a function like strlcpy in c
I tried to create a function like strlcpy, I named it ft_strlcpy. Does my function work like strlcpy?
size_t  ft_strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t dstsize)
{
    size_t  len;

    len = ft_strlen(src);
    if (dstsize)
    {
        while (dstsize-- > 1 && *src)
            *dst++ = *src++;
        *dst = '\0';
    }
    return (len);
}

I tried to ask claud ai, but it told me that the function is not exactly the same.

" is my function work like ft_strlcpy?" Of course ft_strlcpy works as ft_strlcpy..:)

First please try to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it. And while you [edit] your question, also tell us the behavior you expect, and the behavior you actually get.

This would be a good opportunity to learn about automated unit testing. Try to think of as many possibilities for where it could go wrong, code them up to call your function, then use something like memcmp to check the results.

The AI you asked probably have access to at least one implementation of strlcpy and from that draw the conclusion that your function is not exactly the same. Other than that, (assuming size_t (*ft_strlen)(const char*) = strlen;), I can't spot a difference in the result

POSIX strlcpy() has the pointers qualified with restrict.

Pedantic concern: With the soon to be dropped non-2's complement encoding and if char is like signed char, this str...() function does not properly distinguish between -0 and +0 as it uses *src.  String functions have "for all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type unsigned char (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value)." Solved with while (dstsize-- > 1 && *((unsigned char *)src)).

@chux: good point about non-2's complement representation of signed char. In 42 years of C programming (I guess I should celebrate this magic number), I never realised testing char pointer *src for the NUL-terminator could match anything but the all-bits zero NUL byte.   It would be consistent for char to always be unsigned on these architectures but I wonder if other constraints in the C Standard make this compulsory...

@youssef: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score and upvote any that helped you.

@chqrlie signed char and non-2's complement allowed --> Hmmm.  Not likely a SO question but a retro computing one.  In my few experiences with real non-2's complement, I do not recall the sign-ness of their char.

Welcome to StackOverflow @youssef. If an answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer. You can also upvote any helpful answer, as voting and accepting is separate (see here: What should I do when someone answers my question?).

Here is the specification for strlcpy (and strlcat) from the original BSD man pages:

Synopsis
#include <bsd/string.h>

size_t strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t size);
size_t strlcat(char *dst, const char *src, size_t size);

Description
The strlcpy() and strlcat() functions copy and concatenate strings respectively. They are designed to be safer, more consistent, and less error prone replacements for strncpy(3) and strncat(3). Unlike those functions, strlcpy() and strlcat() take the full size of the buffer (not just the length) and guarantee to NUL-terminate the result (as long as size is larger than 0 or, in the case of strlcat(), as long as there is at least one byte free in dst). Note that a byte for the NUL should be included in size. Also note that strlcpy() and strlcat() only operate on true ''C'' strings. This means that for strlcpy() src must be NUL-terminated and for strlcat() both src and dst must be NUL-terminated.
The strlcpy() function copies up to size - 1 characters from the NUL-terminated string src to dst, NUL-terminating the result.
The strlcat() function appends the NUL-terminated string src to the end of dst. It will append at most size - strlen(dst) - 1 bytes, NUL-terminating the result.
Return Values
The strlcpy() and strlcat() functions return the total length of the string they tried to create. For strlcpy() that means the length of src. For strlcat() that means the initial length of dst plus the length of src. While this may seem somewhat confusing, it was done to make truncation detection simple.
Note, however, that if strlcat() traverses size characters without finding a NUL, the length of the string is considered to be size and the destination string will not be NUL-terminated (since there was no space for the NUL). This keeps strlcat() from running off the end of a string. In practice this should not happen (as it means that either size is incorrect or that dst is not a proper ''C'' string). The check exists to prevent potential security problems in incorrect code.

Now regarding your question: Does my function work like strlcpy?:

it does return strlen(src)
it does copy no more than dstsize-1 characters from src, up to the NUL-terminator.
it does NUL-terminate dst, provided dstsize is not 0.

You use a different name for the third argument, but it does not make a functional difference.
Note however that you did not provide the source code for ft_strlen, which can only be assumed to return the length of the string, ie: behave like strlen.
So from my analysis, your function does behave like strlcpy. Whatever thing you asked for advice seems incorrect, and if you tell it so, it will probably agree and tell you why.

@pmg commented that the POSIX standardized version of strlcpy has a slightly different specification as specified in the Open Group man page:
#include <string.h>

size_t strlcat(char *restrict dst, const char *restrict src,
       size_t dstsize);
size_t strlcpy(char *restrict dst, const char *restrict src,
       size_t dstsize);

The restrict qualifier tells the compiler about an additional constraint on the arguments, specified as If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.  This allows the compiler to assume that a modification performed via dst cannot change the bytes accessed via src.
This does not per se change the behavior of the implementation, the case of overlapping source and destination areas was left unspecified in the BSD man page, which may create confusion or false expectations.

What might have triggered the confusion is your unusual loop
while (dstsize-- > 1 && *src)
    *dst++ = *src++;

While correct, it could be written in a more readable style
// copy no more than dstsize - 1 bytes from NUL-terminated src
//   note: dstsize is known to be > 0
for (size_t count = 0; count < dstsize - 1 && *src; count++)
    *dst++ = *src++;

Some creative minds might even prefer:
while (dstsize --> 1 && *src)
    *dst++ = *src++;

This latter style is the topic of this forum's most animated discussion.

Another point is your implementation reads the source string twice: once to measure the length and a second time, at least partially to copy the part that fits in the destination area.  While this is not a visible difference for the caller, it is arguable that this 2 pass approach is inefficient.  Here is an alternative that uses a single pass:
size_t  ft_strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t dstsize)
{
    size_t  i = 0;

    if (dstsize) {
        // copy no more than dstsize - 1 bytes
        while (i < dstsize - 1) {
            char c = src[i];
            dst[i] = c;
            // early stop if the string fits in the destination
            if (c == '\0')
                return i;
            i++;
        }
        dst[i] = '\0';
    }
    // count the remaining bytes in the source string
    while (src[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    return i;
}


Good point about "reads the source string twice".

I'd expect ft_strlcpy() to use restrict pointers to indicate overlapped memories risk undefined behavior (UB).
size_t ft_strlcpy(char *restrict dst, const char *restrict src, size_t dstsize);


If code is to really work without restrict (src and dst may point to overlapping areas), then use that initial len.  OP's code, as-is, has troubles when dst == src + 1, etc.
size_t ft_strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t dstsize) {
    size_t len = ft_strlen(src);

    if (dstsize > 0) {
      size_t copy = min(len, dstsize - 1);
      memmove(dst, src, copy);  // Handles overlapping memory.
      dst[copy] = '\0';
    }
    return len;
}


Good alternative implementation, fully defined for overlapping areas.  In the OP's context (42, Epitech, Epita...), memmove is probably not allowed but they could use their own reimplementation ft_memmove, which is surprisingly difficult to write in a fully defined way per the C Standard.

Agree about _ surprisingly difficult_.
